# MeteorJS Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have this problem with meteor and the error in the client browser is this

> underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:1110 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>   meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   base64.js?1a63019243b73298e2964e6d4680f25bca657726:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   logging.js?07e201b648f16be8435a4f666156995eeda0c750:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   reload.js?da8974b7231dd8c0caccb5f322dcf97329d486d1:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   random.js?fe7b46080c91ce482acf6fc326afbc5b176f0502:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined
>   retry.js?1f1dd2c35d300110fdaba51ce4473583bc3bf031:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined

but in the server there is no error. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your Javascript packages aren't being loaded, are they in the right spot?

Comment: @ScottKaye What do you mean the right spot? How will I know its in the right spot? I did not know what happen the last time it works now its got error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proxy or CDN in between you and the server or your browser cache isn't refreshing the file.

You've requested `meteor.js` which isn't a complete file (cut off half way). This is is the cause of the Unexpected End of file error.

Clear your cache, or force your proxy/CDN to refresh the file's record.

Comment: I think you right.  I tried to used incognito window in chrome the error does not exist. I tried to delete cookies but still the error exist in chrome. I tried to used firefox the error did not exist. Any ideas how to let it work in chrome?

Comment: @ChrisIan You have to clear your cache. See https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en-GB. Make sure you enable `Empty the Cache` when you do it.

Comment: A quick way to disable cache is using Chrome's "inspect element" -> Network -> [ X ] Disable Cache.
Enable this checkbox and reload the chrome tab, once it loads completely you can un-select it and proceed as  normally.